# When to use FancyArrow and when to use FancyArrowPatch in matploltib? and what is the key difference between the two?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I noticed that using `FancyArrow` or `FancyArrowPatch` is most flexible way for me to adjust arrow properties in matplotlib. However, I am confused now: **Is there any fundamental difference between the two ?** **Is there any situation where one is perferred over the other ?**

minimum code for using both is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrow
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
# FancyArrow
a1 = FancyArrow(0, 0, 0.4, 0.4)
ax.add_patch(a1)
# FancyArrowPatch
a2 = FancyArrowPatch((1,1), (0.5, 0.5), color='r')
ax.add_patch(a2)
```